# No patch files found when yarn install

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, yarnpkg, patch-package

I have to clone a new react native project today, but when I yarn install it always returns a "no patch files found" error. Does anyone have any idea to fix this problem?
[no_patch_files_found_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHw1t.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using patch-package and it does not find any patches then you will get this message, if your team or the project is having in their system ask them to push commit and push the same.

thanks :)